# KMDF USB Device Stop, Remove or Disable

Tags: usb, driver, device, kmdf

I develope KMDF with MS sample code. On an event call, I want to disable a specified device. 
IRP_MJ_PNP come, and I can catch some MN irp. Here is some code to register the callback function.

```
WdfFdoInitSetFilter(DeviceInit);

WdfDeviceInitSetDeviceType(DeviceInit, FILE_DEVICE_BUS_EXTENDER);

status = WdfDeviceInitAssignWdmIrpPreprocessCallback(
    DeviceInit,
    WdfFltrWdmPnp,
    IRP_MJ_PNP,
    NULL,
    0);
```

I can get the hardware id. In the past, in user mode application, I could remove the device driver with `Setup~, cm_~` API. Can I use this API in the driver code? If not, how can I stop or remove the device driver? Or the device?